# Symfony & Doctrine broke tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Strange behaviour on a Symfony projet.
I'm running Symfony 3.4 and using MariaDB as my DB server.

Sometimes, some tables of MariaDB Server became unavailable (error 1146 table doesn't exist), it happens on my dev server (running ubuntu 16.04) and on my pre-production server (running Centos 7 with plesk). Tried to repair but the mysql tool give me the error "table doesn't exists".

I'm using phpMyAdmin to navigate trough my DB, i can still see the table but if i try to access to it, it gives me the 1146 error "table doesn't exist". The .frm file is still present on the server, if i delete it, it disapear from phpmyadmin but if i try to recreate it, i got the "table already exists" error.

To be honest i don't know where to look at. I got the error on two different servers. It happends only my dev and pre-production server.

If anybody have an idea about that, please share your knowledge !

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: run `php bin/console d:s:update --dump-sql`

Comment: try to restart maria service

Comment: I don't think there is much we can do, as this sounds hard to reproduce. Could you maybe provide a minimal example? In any case you could check which `serverVersion` you are using in your DATABASE_URL. If it's set to `5.7` this might be the result of incompatible queries with your MariaDB version. See: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/configuration.html#automatic-platform-version-detection